# dotnet publish, Core project with framework references, fails with release configuration

Tags: .net-5, dotnet-publish

Publishing in release configuration gives this error:

> Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(97,5): error MSB4062: The
> "EnsureBindingRedirects" task could not be loaded from the assembly
> ...\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

> The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the
> `<UsingTask>` declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
> dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
> that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask

This is my publish command:

```
dotnet publish  .\MyProject.csproj --runtime win10-x64
--self-contained --configuration release
```

- If I omit the configuration parameter the build is successful.
- Building with Visual Studio (msbuld) works with debug or release configurations.

This is a .Net 5 project that references projects that use .Net framework 4.7.2 projects.

Comment: Did you try to restore the project via CLI before the publish command? You could try updating your dependencies or clearing the cached packages first then doing a restore.
Also, if you remove the reference to this package will the project compile successfully?

Comment: The publish should do a restore, but I also did it explicitly and still get the problem.

I can't delete the package.  It's part of the old framework code, which other use.  In order to remove it, I had to remove Microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client   and Microsoft.net.http, and then the project wouldn't build.